# Trouble converting number from query result to float in the template

Tags: django, parsefloat, tofixed

i have an sql stored procedure returning me values (Characteristics and their value).

The values are real in the table, fixed to 2 decimals, the table doesn't seem to be the problem since the numbers are stored properly.

The problem come when i load my template (i use Python+Django), those value are listed in a tab :

```
<table id="regnorme3Tab" name="regnorme3Tab" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th style="width:200px">Libellé</th>
                <th>Limite inf</th>
                <th>Valeur</th>
                <th>limite sup</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for reg_norme in reg_savs %}
              {%if reg_norme.Saisie == 'O' %}
              <tr name="Reg_Normes" id="{{reg_norme.regauxnormes}}">
              <th><span> {{reg_norme.Id}}</span></th>
              <th class="codevalue"><span> {{reg_norme.Code}}</span></th>
              <th style="width:200px"><span> {{reg_norme.LibEtendu}}</span></th>
              <th><span> {{reg_norme.LimitInf}}</span></th>
              <th><span><input type="number" max="{{reg_norme.LimitSup}}" step="0.01" min="{{reg_norme.LimitInf}}"class="{{reg_norme.Code}}"  id="{{reg_norme.Id}}" value="{{reg_norme.Valeur}}" required style="width:40px;"></span></th>
              <th><span> {{reg_norme.LimitSup}}</span></th>
              </tr>
              {%endif%}
           {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

If i leave things like that, nothing is displayed in my input, i had the same problem on some isolated number input and i managed to display the data by using parseFloat() and toFixed(2).

```
document.getElementById('ebHumValue').value = parseFloat({{displayHUMHumidite}}).toFixed(2);
```

So i though i would create a function with a loop on my tab and use parseFloat and toFixed to display something.

```
$("#regnorme3Tab :input").each(function () {
var number = this.name;
this.value = number;
alert(parseFloat(this.name).toFixed(2));
});
```

The function is in document.ready so it would format the number correctly after loading.

But the problem is that i doesn't work in the tab, i tried to display the value at different stage, for reason i don't understand first it change from like 22.4 (in the table) to 22.3999945754 when i print it, when i use parseFloat() on it, it become 22 and even if i use toFixed(2) with it, it become 22.00 and i don't really get why since the same conversion on isolated input work on my page.

Any idea why the base value get changed like that in the first place ? And how i can manage to cast that so it would display the correct number ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried to use the template gabarit floatformat builtin ?

`{{ displayHUMHumidite |floatformat:2 }}`

source here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't work, it display nothing in the input